# How do touch functions trigger correctly when used in a scroll group (corona)?

Tags: lua, scroll, touch, coronasdk, lua-table

## Touch Functions in a Scroll Group

I am attempting to add touch event listeners to objects that are placed in a scroll group. The scroll part is working fine, but the "ended" part of the touch function never registers.

I have seen that others have had this problem, but their solutions never fixed my problem - I have not though seen any using tables. In my code below it implements the code that fixed other people's problems.

I have tried re-organizing everything in different orders but that did not seem to change anything.

```
local widget = require("widget")

local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
   left = 100,
   top = 200,
   width = 900,
   height = 500,
   maskFile = "white.png"
   scrollWidth = 2000,
   scrollHeight = 400,
   hideBackground = true,
   friction = 0.9 --0 is slowest
}
scrollView.x = 0
scrollView.y = H/2 - scrollView.height/2
```

The scroll screen above works fine...

```
local page = {}
page[1] = {exists = true}
page[2] = {exists = true}
page[3] = {exists = true}
page[4] = {exists = true}
page[5] = {exists = true}
page[6] = {exists = true}
page[7] = {exists = true}
page[8] = {exists = true}
page[9] = {exists = false}
page[10] = {exists = false}
```

Above I created a table.

```
for i = 1,#page do
    if page[i].exists == true then
        page[i].img = display.newImage("images/"..myScene..i..".png") --makes the different page link images    
    else
        page[i].img = display.newImage("images/coming.png")
    end
    page[i].img:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint)
    page[i].img.x = (W+(i*2*W))/9 - 2*W/8 + 50 
            page[i].img.y = scrollView.height/4+20
    
    if i > #page/2 then
        page[i].img.x = (W+((i-#page/2)*2*W))/9 - 2*W/8 + 50
        page[i].img.y = page[i].img.y + scrollView.height/2-20
    end
    

    local img = page[i].img
```

I rename it as a local variable because touch functions do not like [ ]

```
    scrollView:insert(img)
    group:insert(scrollView)

    function img:touch(e)
        if e.phase == "began" then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( img )
            img.isFocus = true

        elseif e.phase == "moved" then

                            local dx = math.abs( e.x - e.xStart ) 
                            local dy = math.abs( e.y - e.yStart ) 

                            if dx > 10 or dy > 10 then
                                  scrollView:takeFocus( event ) 
                            end
```

The above part is what supposedly fixes this problem for others..
It checks if the x- or y-transition is more than 10 put the focus to my scrollview

```
        elseif e.phase == "ended" then --it never gets to this part...
            if page[i].exists == true then
                storyboard.gotoScene(myScene..i)
            else
                audio.play(soon)
            end
        end
    end
    img:addEventListener("touch")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your img:touch(e) function, you need to add "return true" right before the last end ... like below.  Also, you can remove the extra code in the function which is not necessary ( setFocus (img) and img.isFocus = true ).  I've found that that code does not perform well on Android devices.

Use the code below instead and it should work.

```
function img:touch(e)
    if e.phase == "began" then
        -- do something here
    elseif e.phase == "moved" then
        local dx = math.abs( e.x - e.xStart ) 
        local dy = math.abs( e.y - e.yStart ) 
        if dx > 10 or dy > 10 then
            scrollView:takeFocus( event ) 
        end
    elseif e.phase == "ended" then
        if page[i].exists == true then
            storyboard.gotoScene(myScene..i)
        else
            audio.play(soon)
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

Comment: It now gives me the following error when I select the image:                                                                                  /Applications/CoronaSDK/Corona Terminal: line 9: 54097 Segmentation fault: 11  "$path/Corona Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Corona Simulator" $*
logout

[Process completed] ---And then it crashes...

Comment: I received more of the code. The crash appears to be because widget = require("widget") was local to enter scene instead of local to the file or the entire scene.   Moving it out of enter scene solved the crash